# How to update DataGridViewComboBoxCell value without leaving cell or pressing enter? C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

Basically the problem is that I have a `comboBox` inside a `DataGrid` , When I change the information inside the `comboBox` I have to Click in other cell to run an event, How can I run the event immediately when I change the value of the `comboBox`.

```
public void DataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   //My Code Here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the cellvaluechanged event only fires when you select another cell. Have you tried to use a selectedindexchanged on your combobox?

Comment: I haven't tried, until now, but it does not have a different effect

Comment: It appears to work with a normal comboBox, at least in the examples that I found, but I can't get it work inside a DataGridView

Comment: have you tried to refresh the datagridview on the combobox event?